# show/hide multiple selectors on the respective selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to Jquery, I have a requirement to show extra text only when mouse hover on the respective line

How can i change my jquery snippet without writing the same snippets 10 times for 10 different selectors

here the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script >
        jQuery(function() {

        $("#demoTable1").hide();
        $( "#demo1" ).mouseover(function() {
                $("#demoTable1").show();
            });
            $( "#demo1" ).mouseout(function() {
                $("#demoTable1").hide();
            });

        $("#demoTable2").hide();
        $( "#demo2" ).mouseover(function() {
                $("#demoTable2").show();
            });
            $( "#demo2" ).mouseout(function() {
                $("#demoTable2").hide();
            });

        });
    </script>
<style>
    tr {
            background: #b8d1f3;
            }

        td {
            font-size: 12px;

            color: #000;
            }
</style>
 </head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id='demo1'> Service : All services are running 
                <div id='demoTable1'> some text here 1 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id='demo2'> Service : All services are running 
                <div id='demoTable2'> some text here 2 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using pure CSS, just make sure the element you are wanting to show is directly after the parent.

```css
.child {
    display: none;
}
.parent:hover .child {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">Hover over me
    <div class="child">I will appear</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Its exactly suits my requirement. Its working now

Comment: You're welcome! If it correctly answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like:

```js
$("[id^='demoTable']").hide();
$("[id^='demo']").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find("div").show();
});
$("[id^='demo']").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find("div").hide();
});
```

```css
tr {background: #b8d1f3;}
td {font-size: 12px;color: #000;padding: 10px;}
div {padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='demo1'> Service : All services are running
      <div id='demoTable1'> some text here 1 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='demo2'> Service : All services are running
      <div id='demoTable2'> some text here 2 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique you're looking for is called 'Don't Repeat Yourself', or DRY. The simplest way to achieve that in your case is to use `class` attributes to group elements with common functionality. You can then use DOM traversal within the event handlers attached to those elements to find the related content and amend it.

In this case you can use the `hover()` event to `toggle()` the child `div` element, something like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".demo").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".demo-table").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
td {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
}
.demo-table { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="demo"> Service : All services are running
      <div class="demo-table"> some text here 1 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="demo"> Service : All services are running
      <div class="demo-table"> some text here 2 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*With that being said*, JS is not the best technology to use for this. CSS is far more appropriate, using the `:hover` pseudo-selector:

```css
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
td {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
}
.demo-table { display: none; }
.demo:hover .demo-table { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="demo"> Service : All services are running
      <div class="demo-table"> some text here 1 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="demo"> Service : All services are running
      <div class="demo-table"> some text here 2 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not exactly the "simplest", as using pure CSS works as well

Comment: @JaredBledsoe The simplest remark is referring to a DRY JS solution. I was in the process of editing in the complete answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Parameterizing jquery should be easy. Give each td a class of 'demo' and the inner div a class of 'demoTable'. Then you can do somethingl ike this:

```
$( ".demo" ).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".demoTable").show();
});
$(".demo").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find(".demoTable").hide();
});
```